# Find exact word in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I would like to find the extract word in specific column using MySQL query. Here my table name demo and column name "words", which contain value "அன்பே". I want to find exact "அன்பே".

I used below querys

```
create table demo(words nvarchar(200));

insert into demo values (N'அன்பே');

select * from demo where words=N'அன்பே';

select * from demo where words like N'அன்பே';
```

These two select query couldn't work.

Comment: What do you mean the two select queries didn't work? They work just fine for me on both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8. What specific behavior are you expecting you aren't getting?

Comment: I'm also using MySQL 5.7 but didn't work. I want only  "அன்பே" row.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Result showing like that 'Empty set'

Comment: are you using utf8mb4?

Comment: I tried that also and utf8 but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use correct charsets (and in comparing - correct collation):

> ```
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
> SET character_set_client=utf8mb4;
> SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;
> SET character_set_results=utf8mb4;
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
> ```
>
> | Variable_name | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | character_set_client | latin1 |
> | character_set_connection | latin1 |
> | character_set_database | latin1 |
> | character_set_filesystem | binary |
> | character_set_results | latin1 |
> | character_set_server | latin1 |
> | character_set_system | utf8 |
> | character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
>
> | Variable_name | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | character_set_client | utf8mb4 |
> | character_set_connection | utf8mb4 |
> | character_set_database | latin1 |
> | character_set_filesystem | binary |
> | character_set_results | utf8mb4 |
> | character_set_server | latin1 |
> | character_set_system | utf8 |
> | character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |

> ```
> create table demo(words nvarchar(200) ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
> insert into demo values (_utf8mb4'அன்பே');
> SELECT * FROM demo;
>
> select * from demo where words='அன்பே';
>
> select * from demo where words like 'அன்பே';
> ```
>
> ```
> | words           |
> | :-------------- |
> | அன்பே |
>
> | words           |
> | :-------------- |
> | அன்பே |
>
> | words           |
> | :-------------- |
> | அன்பே |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9b0b20536b0c266233256f45dc30171d)*

Comment: The demo table contains 10 rows means select query working fine.  But I have 1 lakhs above rows it didn't work.

Comment: @Avisha *I have 1 lakhs above rows it didn't work.* The workability cannot depend on the rows amount !!! Maybe you mean that the query needs too much time for to execute? but this is absolutely unrelated problem/task. Create according index: ```CREATE INDEX idx_name ON demo (words)```, it must improve.